# Como resolver o problema com a rota no node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Usando o node.js, esse aplicativo deveria preencher o terminal com tweets (o nome do arquivo é `tweet_counter.js`):

```
var ntwitter = require('ntwitter'),
credentials = require('./credentials.json'),
twitter;

twitter = ntwitter(credentials);

twitter.stream(
    'statuses/filter',
    {"track" : ["awesome", "cool", "rad", "gnarly", "groovy"] },

    function(stream){
        stream.on('data', function(tweet){
            console.log(tweet.text);
        });
    }
);
```

É uma API do Twitter, que usa a credenciais disponibilizadas pelo twitter, que foram salvas no arquivo `credentials.json`, salvo na pasta raiz do projeto junto com o `tweet_counter.js`:

[image: Posição das Pastas]

Mas ao ser executado no terminal exibe esse erro:
[image: Erro de Execução]

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir esse erro?
Desde já, muito obrigada!

Comment: Esse módulo é este -> https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter? 
Se fôr está abandonado.

Comment: Mas existe alguma outra API que eu possa instalar para o mesmo aplicativo?

Comment: No site do MooTools usamos esta: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter, a parte de stream parece a mesma API que a tua: https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter#streaming-api

Comment: Obrigada! Ele agora não exibe mais erros, mas também não exibe a saída..

Comment: Aparece algo na consola/janela do node?

Comment: Não, eu sei que executou porque não aparece status de erro, mas também não exibe nenhuma saída no terminal

Comment: Muda `console.log(tweet.text);` para `console.log('tweet:', tweet);` aparece alguma coisa?

Comment: Não, não aparece nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme ficou registrado nos comentários desta pergunta, o [módulo ntwitter](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter) foi descontinuado (*DEPRECATED*). Uma alternativa a ele é o módulo [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit). É preciso ver a documentação dessa API, pois algumas funções diferem daquelas que tentei usar anteriormente.

Nesse [repositório](https://github.com/vanribeiro/SolucaoAlternativa_LivroDoSemmy/blob/master/Capitulo6/tweet_counter.js), existe um exemplo de uso do módulo [Twit](https://github.com/vanribeiro/SolucaoAlternativa_LivroDoSemmy/blob/master/Capitulo6/tweet_counter.js).